# Is there a better way to define properties of Objects in Android Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm creating multiple objects using the same class in my project and am defining the properties of those objects in arrays, is there a shorter or tidier way to define all of these properties?

Thanks

```
upgrade[] firstUpgrade;
upgrade[] secondUpgrade;
upgrade[] thirdUpgrade;

// --- CPS ---
int[] firstUpgradeCPS = {0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 10};
int[] secondUpgradeCPS = {10, 20, 39, 56, 78, 100};
int[] thirdUpgradeCPS = {50, 80, 100, 150, 200, 310};

// --- Cost ---
int[] firstUpgradeCosts = {0, 10, 50, 100, 200, 400};
int[] secondUpgradeCosts = {0, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000};
int[] thirdUpgradeCosts = {0, 200, 600, 1000, 3000, 6000};
```

Comment: I've modified my question as I realised what a bad example I gave, each different array contains different values. Each of the arrays are groups of properties for my upgrade[] class.

Comment: Use multidimensional arrays. Even more so, do a low level design and segregate responsibility in appropriate classes.